# The nutshell of the projeft

Tags: grammaticality, idiomatic-language

```
This is basically the nutshell of the project
```

What I want to say is this is basically the summary of the project, is the above sentence grammatical and idiomatic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what I understand, you are trying to explain (or define) your project to someone in the most simplest way possible.

Your sentence, although grammatical, is not idiomatic and does not serve your purpose.

First, the use of "nutshell" in that manner is quite unusual, if not incorrect. Second, if we assume "nutshell" can be used like that, then the use of "basically" is redundant.

From Cambridge dictionary, the correct idiom is *"in a nutshell"* which means *"using as few words as possible"*.

You can say *"[To put it] In a nutshell, the project allows ... (simple explanation here)"* or *"This, in a nutshell, is what the project is about (assuming you have explained the project before)"*.

Have a look at "gist", "to put it simply", "essence", etc.

You could make it even more simple by saying *"This is basically what the project is about."*